# Symfony 3.4. Not any route is working - No route found for "GET /

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony-3.4

My Symfony 3.4 project does not recognize any route anymore. Debugging routes in terminal (php bin/console debug:router) does show all the routes but app_dev.php keeps giving error messages. Routing is enabled and set correct in routing.yml file.

Clearing cache also did not work.

mail_chimp:
    resource: "@MailChimpBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

```
/**
 * @Route("/klanten/lijst")
 */
public function klantenLijstAction() {
    return;
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzDNj.png)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[> the routing tries to match routes one by one in the order of their definitions; whenever one matches, work is done](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18415#issuecomment-204755604).

In the routes-list image, you look to have three (maybe more) routes to answer the URL '/'. Which single one should run a controller action?

You should probably set prefixes for the URLs that aren't the index route.